# Is it possible to bind port 443 to HTTP on IIS?

Tags: iis

Is it possible to use port 443 on http?

I am adding a new binding as http on 443. There is no other bindings as well. But IIS can not be started. It says that another web site may be using the same port.

I use nestat. But I could not find a solution.

Thanks for your help?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution but I am not sure. There may be side effects.

I changed IP address of the binding in site bindings dialog box on IIS. Instead of all unassigned I used specific IP address.

Comment: Here is a link for MSDN blog: 'Bind multiple sites on same IP address and Port in SSL' that might be helpful:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varunm/archive/2013/06/18/bind-multiple-sites-on-same-ip-address-and-port-in-ssl.aspx

Answer (score 0):

"HTTPS URLs begin with "https://" and use port 443 by default, whereas HTTP URLs begin with "http://" and use port 80 by default."  Source:  [Wikipedia, HTTP Secure/HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure).  Port 443 is categorised as  [well-known port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)#Common_port_numbers).

Comment: Those are the default, but a website could run on port 80, 81 or 443 or whatever. the client needs to connect to `http://server:443` but a lot of firewalls might block this, so it still isn't a good idea to use 443

Answer (score 0):

It's yet another limitation imposed by the IIS Manager GUI, you can bind to *:443 over HTTP using the appcmd.exe CLI tool!

Or as you found out, bind to just a single IP instead of all from the UI